# Why does envsubst replace /

Tags: bash

I'm on windows running bash and I can't figure out why this is happening.

I have a variable such as
`export SOCKET=/socket` then when I run `echo '$SOCKET' | envsubst` I get `C:/Program Files/Git/socket`. For some reason it is replacing the slash.

Any idea why this is happening? If i look at the output of `printenv` the only environment variable with Git in the path is `EXEPATH=C:\Program Files\Git`

Comment: Your implementation of `envsubst` would appear to be replacing the absolute pathname in whatever virtual file system `bash` sees with the "real" Windows path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realized once I read @chepner's comment about path mangling that this likely has to do with bash on windows doing a path conversion.

I then tried setting `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` which is supposed to prevent path conversion, and now it works fine. Thanks!